# Overlapping in Masonry onload

Tags: masonry

I'm having the classic overflow problem with masonry. I'm trying to load twitter cards but onload, they are still overlapping each other. They work once the screen is resized.  FYI, I have imageLoad and masonry in there for sure. I'm doing this in rails so not sure how I would make a jsfiddle.  Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.container').imagesLoaded( function(){
$('.container').masonry({
    columnWidth: '.tweet-box',
   itemSelector: '.tweet-box'
  });
 });
});
```

index.html.erb:

```
<main class="container">
  <% @tweet.search("cnn").take(9).each do |j| %>
<section class="tweet-box">
  <p>
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p><a href=<%=j.uri %> data-datetime="2011-11-07T20:21:07+00:00"></a></blockquote>
  <script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </p>
</section>
    <% end %>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing my problem with some recursion. FYI, I don't know if this is the best fix but it got it working for me. Open to a better answer if someone has anything.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

check_size();
check_width();

});

function check_size()
{
if($('.tweet-box').first().height() == 0)
{
    // alert('loop called: ' + $('.tweet-box').first().height())
    setTimeout('check_size()', 20);
}
else
{
    // alert('initialized!!!! boo-ya')
    var $container = $('.container').imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.isotope({
          // options
          itemSelector: '.tweet-box',
          layoutMode: 'masonry'
      });
    });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me, with the imagesloaded script installed.

```
<script src="/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
 docReady(function() {

  var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var msnry;

  imagesLoaded( grid, function() {
    // init Isotope after all images have loaded
    msnry = new Masonry( grid, {
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a combination of the small script "imagesloaded" and a few additional lines of jQuery that fire masonry after all images are loaded did the trick. My page footer now looks like this:

```
<script src="/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#catalogue').imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('#catalogue').masonry({
     columnWidth: 10,
     itemSelector: '.item',
     isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
     /* isFitWidth: true */ 
    });
  });
</script>
```

I don't remember where I got the pinter from, but the script `imagesloaded` can be found here: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded